# How do I get a pointer to the end of my struct?

Tags: c, pointers, embedded

I have a custom memCopy() function from a TI motorware project.
The function takes a start address pointer, an end address pointer and a destination address pointer.

`void memCopy(uint16_t *srcStartAddr,uint16_t *srcEndAddr,uint16_t *dstAddr)`

I want to use this function to copy a structure from Flash into a copy of that structure in RAM.
I'm trying save those addresses as pointers as below.

```
uint16_t *start;
uint16_t *end; 
uint16_t *dest;

start = (uint16_t *)&myStructInFlash;
end = (uint16_t *)(&myStructInFlash + (sizeof(myStructInFlash)));
dest = (uint16_t *)&myStructInRAM;
```

When I step the code through in the debugger, the start and dest pointers look correct, but the end pointer is rubbish. Something like 0xFFFFFFFF I think, it didn't make sense to me anyway.

I assume the problem is with my "address arithmetic".
Is there a proper way to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Colm

Follow up:

Great, thanks Ian. I was not aware that's how pointer arithmetic worked.

As the others have mentioned about the inclusive vs exclusive last address... The function is as follows

```
void memCopy(uint16_t *srcStartAddr,uint16_t *srcEndAddr,uint16_t *dstAddr)
{

  while(srcStartAddr <= srcEndAddr)
    { 
      *dstAddr++ = *srcStartAddr++;
    }

  return;
}
```

From this, I think it would require the "last uint16_t" as opposed to the uint16_t that comes after which (&myStruct + 1) would produce.

How would I obtain the uint16_t just before that? (uint16_t)((&myStruct + 1) - 1) ?

Comment: Do you want `end` to point to "just past the end" of your structure, or to the last byte of that structure? (The former is answered already, the latter is slightly trickier.)

Comment: The answer to this depends entirely on how the section is flash is defined. Is it defined as a C variable and if so of what type? Or is it just a chunk of for example data flash, of which the compiler knows nothing? Apart from that, you also seem to have the usual beginner bugs with pointer arithmetic, as addressed by the posted answer.

Comment: Also, "TI" should make you cringe and then get alert about possible exotic core weirdness, or at least alignment requirements. What CPU is this for, specifically?

Comment: @AdrianMole 
I'm testing it now with Ian's answer to find out, but I think it needs to be the last byte/uint16_t

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes I believe it is the last byte of the structure case.
So following Ian's method of getting the end address of `(&myStruct +1)` , I then fed the start, end, and destination addresses in to the function as:
`memCopy(start, end-1, dest);`
And it worked as intended.

Comment: @Lundin TMS320F28069M

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Addition of a pointer and integer is scaled up by the size of the dereferenced type of the pointer. So to find the address just past the end of an object, add 1 to the address produced by the `&` "address of" operator acting on the object:

- `&myStructInFlash` points to the start of `myStructInFlash`.
- `&myStructInFlash + 1` points just past the end of `myStructInFlash`.

Also, subtraction of two pointers of compatible type is scaled down by the size of the dereferenced type of the pointers, so:

- The expression `(&myStructInFlash + 1 - &myStructInFlash) == 1` is true.

If those addresses are converted to `char *` (or some other narrow character pointer type) then since `sizeof(char)==1` is true by definition:

- `(char *)&myStructInFlash` points to the first byte of `myStructInFlash`.
- `(char *)(&myStructInFlash + 1)` points to the byte just past the end of `myStructInFlash`.
- The expression `(char *)&myStructInFlash + sizeof(myStructInFlash) == (char *)(&myStructInFlash + 1)` is true.
- The expression `(char *)(&myStructInFlash + 1) - (char *)&myStructInFlash == sizeof(myStructInFlash)` is true.

```
uint16_t *start;
uint16_t *end; 
uint16_t *dest;

start = (uint16_t *)&myStructInFlash;
end = (uint16_t *)(&myStructInFlash + 1);
dest = (uint16_t *)&myStructInRAM;
```

Note: For the above code to be correct, `&myStructInFlash` and `&myStructInRAM` must be suitably aligned for conversion to `uint16_t *`, and `sizeof(myStructInFlash)` must be a multiple of `_Alignof(uint16_t)`.  Additionally, `memCopy()` will no doubt require `(char *)end - (char *)start` to be a multiple of `sizeof(uint16_t)`.

---

**EDIT**: According to the comment from OP, `end` should actually point to the last `uint16_t` of the data, not just past the end of the data, so the assignment to `end` should be:

```
end = (uint16_t *)(&myStructInFlash + 1) - 1;
```

Comment: Your answer kind of says this, but it is worth pointing out explicitly: This method calculates end point as byte *after* the last byte. If `memCopy` treats `srcEndAddr` as inclusive, then additional computation is needed.

Comment: Also note that `memCopy` takes `uint16_t*` pointers - this could potentially complicate things if that function works using pointer arithmetic on that type.

Comment: @AdrianMole AIUI the `memCopy` function is taken from another project, so I guess it does the right thing. (The base type is `uint16_t` probably because of some flash and/or DMA channel requirement.)

Comment: Great, thanks Ian. I was not aware that's how pointer arithmetic worked.

As the others have mentioned about the inclusive vs exclusive last address...
The function is as follows

void memCopy(uint16_t *srcStartAddr,uint16_t *srcEndAddr,uint16_t *dstAddr)
{

  while(srcStartAddr <= srcEndAddr)
    { 
      *dstAddr++ = *srcStartAddr++;
    }

  return;
}

From this, I think it would require the "last uint16_t" as opposed to the uint16_t that comes after which (&myStruct + 1) would produce.

How would I obtain the uint16_t just before that?
(uint16_t)((&myStruct + 1) - 1)  ?

Comment: @ColmMurphy You would need to subtract 1 from the `uint16_t *` pointer, so `end = (uint16_t *)(&myStruct + 1) - 1` (or so you can see your mistake with the position of the parentheses: `((uint16_t *)(&myStruct + 1) - 1)`).

Answer (score 0):

You could just copy one byte at a time:

```c
uint16_t numBytes = sizeof(myStructInFlash);

for(uint16_t thisByte; thisByte<numBytes; thisByte++)
{
    *((uint8_t*)dstAddr + thisByte) = *((uint8_t*)srcStartAddr + thisByte);
}
```